# move a method from mainActivity to a class file

Tags: java, android, class

i have the following method inside mainActivity but i am trying to move it to separate class file so i can call it in other activities

```
public void addUser(){


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            constants.register_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", "value");
            params.put("email", "value");
            params.put("password", "value");
            return params;
        }
    };

    requestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

i have created a class called 'aqlCalls' and tried to put this and other methods inside but i can't figure how to do that..
any help appreciated..

Comment: Explain *"but i can't figure how to do that"*. What issues are you facing? The first step would be to copy the code over (which I assume you have figured out).

Comment: @codeMagic i had many errors but i fixed them the last one is saying  'cannot resolve method getApplicationContext'

Comment: @OmarAlhadidy does any answer helps you to find the solution?

Comment: Please accept the answer that works for you @OmarAlhadidy https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own listener to communicate with the activities and set the method static and save inside a class, passing the Context and use it in the request call.

```
public static void addUser(Context context, AddUserListener listener){
...
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                listener.onSucces(response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.onError(error.getMessage())
            }
        })
```

The Listener should be:

```
public interface AddUserListener{
    void onSuccess(String response);
    void onError(String message)
}
```

And finally in the activity do this:

```
MyClass.addUser(getApplicationContext(), new AddUserListener {
   @Override
   void onSuccess(String response){
      ... //Toast.makeText(...)
   }
   @Override
   void onError(String message){
      ...//Toast.makeText(...)
   }
});
```

***Notice:***
Please if you receive any Exception write down in your post, maybe you will receive an exception related with MainThread

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try to find the exact problem firstly.

According to the code in your method, I guess the problem is the `Toast`. If you want to use the Toast outside the Activity, you need to pass the context to this method. If you search for "android toast outside activity", you will get a lot of similar questions. such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725458/2000468).

I suggest that adding a new parameter to `context` the addUser() and use the context to show the Toast.

And when using this method, pass a context (such as `getApplicationContext()`) to the method.

for example

```
void addUser(Context mcontext){
   //all the toast usage change to 
   Toast.makeText(mContext, ....)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking like something like this:

```
public class aqlCalls {

   public static void addUser(Context context) {
       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, constants.register_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", "value");
            params.put("email", "value");
            params.put("password", "value");
            return params;
        }
       };
       requestHandler.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
   }
}
```

Then you can call it from your class with:

```
public class OtherClass{
   static void yourMethode() {
      aqlCalls.addUser();
   }
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is one error 'cannot resolve method getApplicationContext'  do you have any idea why?

Comment: I think because the methode is static. Maybe try to replacethe "GetApplicationContext()" this "context"