# Kotlin - Initializing SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm attempting to load and save data using sharedpreferences in Kotlin, specifically using the Android Studio.

I'm getting this error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'android.content.SharedPreferences
> android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
> on a null object reference

Pointing at my initialization of shared preferences.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {

   private val dragonstats by lazy {getSharedPreferences("DRAGON_STATS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}
```

I get the same error if I write it this way:

```
val dragonstats = getSharedPreferences("DRAGON_STATS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

I've seen in other answers to declare it this way:

```
SharedPreferences dragonstats
```

but that doesn't read in Kotlin.

The android.com file on Shared preferences says to declare it this way:

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

but that gives an unresolved reference error on activity.

How do I initialize a SharedPreferences file so I can store and retrieve data in Kotlin?

---

EDIT:
So, the only thing that has worked to get it functional is to put ? in everything.

I declare it outside of oncreate so I can use it throughout:

```
var dragonstats: SharedPreferences? = null
```

in oncreate I set it:

```
dragonstats = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
```

Then, when I want to call any piece of it, I use ?:

```
exerciselevel = dragonstats?.getInt("exerciselevel", 0)!!
```

I don't understand why this works but nothing else does.

Answer (score 3):

I write it this way.

```
// in global
private lateinit var pref: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
      pref = getSharedPreferences("mysharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    ...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I keep getting: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: I just tried this answer and it works for me in Android Studio 4

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this to initialize preference:

```
val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

To read data:

```
pref.getString("your_key","default_value")
```

To save data:

```
pref.edit().putString("key","value").apply()
```

EDIT:

If you want to make your variable global you can do something like this:

```
lateinit var pref:SharedPreferences
```

and then in onCreate() :

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

Comment: That gets the same error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you call initialization in onCreate() method?

Comment: I'm trying to have the SharedPreferences value be available across all functions, so I'm trying to declare it outside of the oncreate function. I'm a bit of a beginner and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I just started learning Android and Kotlin and the answer suggested by [Jasper Calapini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566602/351688) works for me in Android Studio 4

```
private lateinit var pref: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        pref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var name: String? = pref.getString("my-string", "hello")

        val editor = pref.edit()
        editor.putString("my-string", "value is changed")
        editor.apply()

        println("name = ${name}")  
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

As the error says, you  get a `NullPointerException` because the `Context` is null.
You can of course use this, but be aware that the keyword `this` is implicit:

```
private val dragonstats by lazy {getSharedPreferences("DRAGON_STATS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}
//equivalent to
private val dragonstats by lazy {this.getSharedPreferences("DRAGON_STATS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}
```

> [`this`,] it's the context of current state of the application/object. It lets newly-created objects understand what has been going on. Typically you call it to get information regarding another part of your program (activity and package/application). [See the full answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572553/13227011)

There is only one condition to respect in order not to obtain a NullPointerException: you must have a context of the application/activity. To do this, don't forget to call `this.setContentView(R.layout.main)` in your OnCreate() method (again, the keyword `this` is not necessary and may be implicit) which will create the context you are looking for. In other words, it will "initialize" the application context `this`.

If you need SharedPreferences outside of an activity, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725458/13227011).

I think the `private val pref by lazy {}` is the best for the use (because `val`, not `var`, and is initialized in one line of code), but make sure you call `this.setContentView(R.layout.main)` before using `pref`